# How to extract data from xml using jsoup

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, jsoup

How can I access the data inside this xml document using jsoup?

Specifically the F data, i.e F="11"

With what I have tried I only get the 900, 1080, 1260, 0, 180, 360 etc data returned.

```
<DV dataDate="2013-11-11T20:00:00Z" type="Forecast">
<Location i="3604" lat="51.708" lon="-5.055" name="MILFORD HAVEN C.B." country="WALES" continent="EUROPE">
<Period type="Day" value="2013-11-11Z">
<Rep D="W" F="11" G="18" H="100" Pp="15" S="9" T="13" V="MO" W="8" U="1">900</Rep>
<Rep D="W" F="12" G="18" H="100" Pp="52" S="7" T="13" V="VP" W="11" U="0">1080</Rep>
<Rep D="NNW" F="11" G="9" H="96" Pp="59" S="4" T="12" V="VG" W="12" U="0">1260</Rep>
</Period>
<Period type="Day" value="2013-11-12Z">
<Rep D="NW" F="9" G="13" H="88" Pp="80" S="7" T="11" V="VG" W="15" U="0">0</Rep>
<Rep D="NW" F="9" G="13" H="88" Pp="13" S="9" T="11" V="VG" W="7" U="0">180</Rep>
<Rep D="NNW" F="7" G="18" H="86" Pp="2" S="9" T="9" V="VG" W="0" U="0">360</Rep>
<Rep D="NNW" F="7" G="20" H="83" Pp="0" S="11" T="10" V="VG" W="1" U="1">540</Rep>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parse your xml:

```
String xml = "<DV dataDate='2013-11-11T20:00:00Z'....";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Then you can essentially traverse through the document as you would with a html document. For example, if you want to select all of the `<rep>` tags and print the F data:

```
Elements rep = doc.select("rep");
for (Element e : rep) {
    System.out.println(e.attr("f"));
}
```

Will output:

```
11
12
11
9
9
7
7
```

To select only the 4th F value: `rep.get(3).attr("f")` which will be 9.

---

Update:

You could just get the remote file as a `String` first and then use my above code as normal. For example:

```
String xml = Jsoup.connect("http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/3604?res=3hourly&key=2dd5950b-91e1-4671-9d83-625f2ae9cbf5").get().toString();

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try it out. Also how would I select say the 4th F data?

Comment: @J4C3N-14 No problem. See my updated answer for selecting the 4th F data.

Comment: Hi just trying your answer, what if I don't have the file locally and connecting like this:             docWeather2 = Jsoup.connect("http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/3604?res=3hourly&key=2dd5950b-91e1-4671-9d83-625f2ae9cbf5").timeout(600000).get();   would I need to put the document into a file before attempting to parse it or is the a way like....jsoup.connect.xmlParser("blah,blah,blah")? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very, much it is exactly what I meant. Stackoverflow and users like you are a godsend, Thank you for your help.